# \pagenumbering{Roman} does not work after it is set

Tags: bibliographies

At the end of my thesis I am using `\printbibliography` to print my bibliography. All is well but afterwards I want to add my appendix like this:

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
text texxt text

\printbibliography % This ends with my last arabic numbering 100

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\begin{appendix}
\include{xy} % This page should have either Roman I or IV as I already started using for my title page etc.
\end{appendix}
```

But now my compiled document has my bibliography with I and my included appendix with II.

With this I can decide myself where my Roman numbering should start again. In this case with 9 which is the same as IX.

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
text text text
\printbibliography
\clearpage\pagenumbering{Roman}\setcounter{page}{9}
\begin{appendix}
\include{more text}
\end{appendix}
```

But how can I have LaTeX do it automatically? I want to replace 9 with something like this:

```
\clearpage\pagenumbering{Roman}\setcounter{page}{macro/function to look for the last used Roman and insert it +1}
```

Comment: put `\clearpage` or `\newpage` after `\printbibliography` and before the change of page numbering style.

Comment: great thank you very much it works. Is there a way to start the roman numbering? For example, if my toc, lof, lot, etc are I, II, III, IV, ... then comes arabic numbering and now I want the appendix to start with V, VI, VII instead of I

Comment: @barbarabeeton One should say `\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{Roman}\setcounter{page}{<num>}` where `<num>` is the number to start from, rather than one less.

Comment: @egreg thank you. that works great :D is there a way to do it automatically ? I mean if I remove II everything would decrease by one and thus my appendix would be wrong.

Comment: @sceiler Can you update your question with the details you gave in the comments?

Answer (score 5):

It's important to go to a new page when changing numbering scheme; this is the cause for your problem: when you issue `\pagenumbering{Roman}` the bibliography page hasn't yet been shipped out.

The scheme could be like this, also for resuming the page numbering:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report} % works also without the twoside option
\usepackage{lipsum}

% a counter to store the last page number in the front matter
\newcounter{rememberpage}

\begin{document}

% Start the front matter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

Text to fill up some pages.

\lipsum[1-12]

% End of the front matter
% First go to a new page (odd page if twoside)
\cleardoublepage
% store the current page number
\setcounter{rememberpage}{\value{page}}

% start the main matter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

Some other text

\lipsum[1-12]

\printbibliography

% End of the main matter
% Go to a new page (odd page if twoside)
\cleardoublepage
% Set up Roman numbering
\pagenumbering{Roman}
% Restore the remembered page number
\setcounter{page}{\value{rememberpage}}

% Start the appendices
\appendix

Now the appendix text

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I wouldn't change back the numbering to Roman for the appendices, but if you're required to do it …